# How to assign values to ndarray variable using loops in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

Defined an ndarray `a` with *dtype* as *object* and filled it with a *dictionary*

```
a = np.ndarray(shape=(2,3,4), dtype=object)
a.fill({'position':(0,0,0)})
```

This is the value of `a`

```
array([[[{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}],
    [{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}],
    [{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}]],

   [[{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}],
    [{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}],
    [{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 0)}]]], dtype=object)
```

I want to replace each *tuple* in the *dictionary* to a **tuple(X-index, Y-index, Z-index)**. I tried `numpy.ndenumerate` loop to assign values as in following code

```
for (x_index, y_index, z_index), temp in np.ndenumerate(a):
    a[x_index][y_index][z_index]['position'] = (x_index, y_index, z_index)
```

Each *tuple* gets assigned to the latest value **(1, 2, 3)**. The value of `a` is

```
array([[[{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}]],

   [[{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 3)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}]]], dtype=object)
```

How can I get the desired output as

```
array([[[{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 1)},
     {'position': (0, 0, 2)}, {'position': (0, 0, 3)}],
    [{'position': (0, 1, 0)}, {'position': (0, 1, 1)},
     {'position': (0, 1, 2)}, {'position': (0, 1, 3)}],
    [{'position': (0, 2, 0)}, {'position': (0, 2, 1)},
     {'position': (0, 2, 2)}, {'position': (0, 2, 3)}]],

   [[{'position': (1, 0, 0)}, {'position': (1, 0, 1)},
     {'position': (1, 0, 2)}, {'position': (1, 0, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 1, 0)}, {'position': (1, 1, 1)},
     {'position': (1, 1, 2)}, {'position': (1, 1, 3)}],
    [{'position': (1, 2, 0)}, {'position': (1, 2, 1)},
     {'position': (1, 2, 2)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}]]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `copy by reference` problem. You update one **dictionary** every other will get updated with the same value. That is why every value comes out to be `{'position': (1, 2, 3)}` as it was the **last update**. To solve this problem create **new dictionary** every time.

```
>>> a = np.ndarray(shape=(2,3,4), dtype=object)
>>> for (x_index, y_index, z_index), temp in np.ndenumerate(a):
...     a[x_index][y_index][z_index] = {'position':(x_index, y_index, z_index)}
... 
>>> a
array([[[{'position': (0, 0, 0)}, {'position': (0, 0, 1)},
         {'position': (0, 0, 2)}, {'position': (0, 0, 3)}],
        [{'position': (0, 1, 0)}, {'position': (0, 1, 1)},
         {'position': (0, 1, 2)}, {'position': (0, 1, 3)}],
        [{'position': (0, 2, 0)}, {'position': (0, 2, 1)},
         {'position': (0, 2, 2)}, {'position': (0, 2, 3)}]],

       [[{'position': (1, 0, 0)}, {'position': (1, 0, 1)},
         {'position': (1, 0, 2)}, {'position': (1, 0, 3)}],
        [{'position': (1, 1, 0)}, {'position': (1, 1, 1)},
         {'position': (1, 1, 2)}, {'position': (1, 1, 3)}],
        [{'position': (1, 2, 0)}, {'position': (1, 2, 1)},
         {'position': (1, 2, 2)}, {'position': (1, 2, 3)}]]], dtype=object)
```